# How to replace image on click and reset to original after exiting hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created the following simple script with an image: when you hover over it, a button appears.

HTML:

```
    <div class="show-image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/267/302" />
        <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value="Play" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    div.show-image {
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        margin:5px;}

    div.show-image:hover input
      {
      display: block;
      }

    div.show-image input {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/4kfBz/1/

1) How can I replace the image (and hide the button) once the button gets clicked with a second image (http://placehold.it/267x302)?

2) How can I reset back to the original image once you exist the hover state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo Link : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arulpraba/4kfBz/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="show-image">
    <img src="http://mtrobson.com/files/2012/02/maligne-lake-side-sm.jpg" />
    <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value="Play" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Get the Original image source
var originalImgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

// Change image on button click
$(".the-buttons").click(function() {
    $('img').attr("src", "http://r-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max300/178/17807570.jpg");
});

//Restore image on mouse out
$('.show-image img').mouseout(function() {
    $('img').attr("src", originalImgSrc );
});
```

**Update:**

Demo Link : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arulpraba/4kfBz/5/)

JS:

```
// Get the Original image source
var originalImgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

// Change image on button click
$(".the-buttons").click(function() {
    $('img').attr("src", "http://r-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max300/178/17807570.jpg");
    $(this).addClass("hide");
});

//Restore image on mouse out
$('.show-image img').mouseout(function() {
    $('img').attr("src", originalImgSrc );
    $('.the-buttons').removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! The only problem is that once the image gets changed on button click, the button still says there. I tried adding 

$(this).hide(); after

    $('img').attr("src", "http://r-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max300/178/17807570.jpg");

But then the button won't even come back again. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$(".show-image").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("input").show().click(function() {
        $(this).prev("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/267x302");
        $(this).hide();
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://lorempixel.com/267/302").unbind("click");
});
```

FIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4kfBz/3/

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/4kfBz/2/ but something not working right...?!

Comment: when I click Play the image doesn't change to the new one, and the play button doesn't disappear.

Comment: @Ori -- Updated and posted example

Comment: you rock! Looks fantastic. One last thing though - in my original script the button disappeared if you didn't click on it and you exited hover mode. Now the button stays fixed... how can I hide it when user leaves hover mode too?

Comment: @Ori -- Call `.hide()` on the element leave function